# How to use pretrained model (.pth file ) for text detection

Tags: deep-learning

I have found pre trained FAST-B model which contains weights and biases of lots of different neural network layers. I want to load the model and prepare it in order to use it text detection in images. I tried something like below:

```
# Load your FAST model
model = torch.load('/kaggle/input/fastbase512/fast_base_ctw_512_finetune_ic17mlt.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))

def preprocess_image(image_path):
    # Read the image using OpenCV
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)


    img = np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1))  # Transpose to (channels, height, width)
    img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255.0  # Normalize pixel values (if needed)
    img = torch.from_numpy(img)  # Convert to PyTorch tensor
    img = img.unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension (if your model expects it)
    return img

# Path to your image file
image_path = '/kaggle/input/sadasfsad/img2.png'

# Preprocess the image
input_image = preprocess_image(image_path)

# Perform inference/prediction
with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input_image)
# For example, if your model outputs bounding box coordinates:
predicted_boxes = output  # Replace this with your actual output format

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
for box in predicted_boxes:
    x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = box
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x_min, y_min), (x_max, y_max), (0, 255, 0), 2)  # Draw bounding box

# Show the image with predicted bounding boxes
plt.imshow(image)
```

But I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Can you help how can i load the model and use it for prediction?